# Excel: prepend a text character into a cell with a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a simple formula in my excel sheet that lists, horizontally the number of days in a sequential fashion:

=A1+1

A1 contains a zero (0).

As such, the formula then adds one for each subsequent cell on the row, producing 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

What I would like to do is be able to prepend a text character, "+ " into each cell's formula.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at the concatenate function.

Comment: Thanks, spikey! I'm aware of the concatenate, but I get an error when I use that because once the + is added to the cell, the subsequent functions no longer work. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Concatenating a `+` symbol onto a numeric result renders the result mathematically useless.

Use a *custom number format* of `+0` and you will retain the numeric value in the cell, not text that looks like a number.

Comment: This is the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `=A1+1`, etc, have `="+" & A1+1`

[image]